# Angular Keycloak login (silent)

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, keycloak

Is there a way to login using 'userName' and 'password' directly from angular/client application?

For example something like this?

```
Keycloak.init({username: 'guest', password: 'abc'});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official keycloak javascript [adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter) does not support the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` flow.

It is possible to initialize the adapter with flows other then the default (`Authorization Code` flow).

```
keycloak.init({ flow: 'implicit' })
```

*flow - Set the OpenID Connect flow. Valid values are standard, implicit or hybrid.*

Please note that there are valid reasons **not** to use the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` flow.

From the keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_resource_owner_password_credentials_flow)

> Resource Owner Password Credentials, referred to as Direct Grant in
>   Keycloak, allows exchanging user credentials for tokens. It’s not
>   recommended to use this flow unless you absolutely need to. Examples
>   where this could be useful are legacy applications and command-line
>   interfaces.
>
> There are a number of limitations of using this flow, including:
>
> - User credentials are exposed to the application
> - Applications need login pages
> - Application needs to be aware of the authentication scheme
> - Changes to authentication flow requires changes to application
> - No support for identity brokering or social login
> - Flows are not supported (user self-registration, required actions,
>     etc.)

Additional Resources:
[Why the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type is not Authentication nor Suitable for Modern Applications](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)
[How secure is the OAuth2 "Resource Owner Password Credential" flow for single-page apps?](http://andyfiedler.com/2014/09/how-secure-is-the-oauth2-resource-owner-password-credential-flow-for-single-page-apps)

If you still want/must use the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` flow it should be possible to implement it by yourself. All keycloak specific details needed to implement your own adapter can be found [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#other-openid-connect-libraries).